# How to access a class from Class.forName when that class has a different class loader

Tags: java, scala, sbt, classloader

My situation is as follows:

I have two scala applications, app 1 and app 2. Both use sbt. I ran "publishLocal" in the sbt shell for App 2, and then made App 2 a library in app 1 (I added it as a library dependency in build.sbt). Within app 2, I have a function, *foo*, the line

```
Class.forName(<CLASS NAME>)
```

I want to pass a class path for class *bar* from app 1 to the foo function in app 2, so that I can get use an instance of the bar class in the foo function. However, when I try this, I get a ClassNotFoundException. I have isolated this problem to the fact that the code which calls "Class.forName" is using the bootstrap class loader, and the bar class is loaded using some other class loader. I cannot change the code in app 2, but I can change the code in app 1 - is there a way that I can somehow specify that bar should be loaded with the bootstrap class loader, or in some other way make it discoverable for app 2 in the foo function?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a setup like:

- app1 (= Application)

  - Bar.class
- app2 (= Lib)

  - class with function foo(...) that wants to use Bar.class

where they both were loaded by different classloaders and you want to lookup `Bar.class` inside the `foo` function in `app2`.

Does the `app2` setup have any classpath dependencies on `app1` so that classes of `app1` are actually loadable by `app2`? If not then chances are low that you are able to use that class.

Let's recap what is happening here. Classloaders usually work on a delegation model. Classloaders respecting the delegation model will first check their loacal cache whether the class was already loaded by that classloader before and if not ask their parents whether they know the definition of that class. Only if none of the ancestors knew about that class before the actual bytes defining the class are loaded by the class loader that initiated the lookup chain. In order to load the bytes of that class definition, the classloader will usually check its classpath if there is any JAR archive or directory mentioned that contains the definition. If multiple sources are present that provide the class definition, the first one found will be loaded which could lead to [shadowing issues](https://medium.com/@akhaku/java-class-shadowing-and-shading-9439b0eacb13) down the road if multiple versions of the same class linger around in different archives/directories.

So, if the classpaths of these two applications (or application and library) are setup in a way that they don't have access to the other's Java archive (JAR) they won't be able to even load and lookup the class definitions of the other application. Probably the best advice to give is to extract common classes into an own library, i.e. `commons` or `base`, and add this library to the classpath of both applications so that the application loader of the respective application/library is able to load the class definitions of shared classes.

Note however, the same class definition, i.e. for class `Bar`, loaded by two different classloaders will result in CL1.Bar != CL2.Bar as the classloader who loaded that class definition is a part of that class, meaning that event though the byte representation of the class in both classloaders is identical, the actual `Class<Bar>` object you obtain is different. This quickly may get an issue if you think about returning the class definition loaded in `foo(...)` and compare it in `app1` with some local `Bar.class` and wonder why a check of `barObject.getClass() instanceof Bar` (or the like) is failing, assuming `barObject` is the product returned by `app2.foo()` and `Bar` being `app1.Bar.class`.

In regards to `Class.forName(...)` using the bootstrap classloader: `Class` has actually two `forName(...)` methods present. One only taking the fully qualified class name to return the class object for, which uses the classloader that actually loaded that respective class, which is almost always the boostrap classloader. The second one has the following signature:
[`Class<?> forName(String className, boolean initialize, Classloader loader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) where you can specify the classloader it should use to lookup and load the class definition with. So, as long as you at least have a reference to a class loaded by the other class loader present you can obtain the reference to that classloader via `otherAppObject.getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Further note that if your applications use Java's module capabilities, you might need to open up the modules so that classloaders are actually able to load the definitions for these classes at all.

> ... is there a way that I can somehow specify that bar should be loaded with the bootstrap class loader, or in some other way make it discoverable for app 2 in the foo function?

I don't know about `sbt` TBH, but usually adding the location of the JAR archive of `app1` to the classpath of `app2` should be enough to allow the classloader of `app2` to load, define and return the class definition of classes used in `app1`. As mentioned, extracting common classes used by both to a library that is added to both applications classpath is probably the recommended way.